Nested Set Permutations and their Enumeration
Let $(S_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of sets defined recursively as follows:

$S_1 = \{1\}$
$S_{i+1} = S_i \cup \{S_i, i+1\} \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}$

A permutation $\sigma$ of $S_i$ is deemed valid if it satisfies these conditions:

Internal Order Preservation:

If $a, b \in S_i$ with $a \neq S_{i-1}$ and $b \neq S_{i-1}$, and $a < b$ in the natural ordering of $\mathbb{N}$, then $\sigma^{-1}(a) < \sigma^{-1}(b)$.
For any $j < k < i$, we have $\sigma^{-1}(S_j) < \sigma^{-1}(S_k)$.


Successor Placement: $\sigma^{-1}(i) > \sigma^{-1}(S_{i-1})$.


Is there a closed-form expression or an efficient algorithm to compute the number of valid permutations of $S_i$, denoted $|VP(S_i)|$, for any $i \in \mathbb{N}$.

"Thus, each $S_i$ is a finite set containing the natural numbers from $1$ to $i$, and also all preceding sets $S_j$ for $j < i$.": this does not match the way you defined $S_{i+1}$ in the preceding line; the way you defined it, $S_{i+1}={1,\ldots,i+1}$.

I don't think I understand the definition.  If $\sigma^{-1}(i) > \sigma^{-1}(x)$ for all $x \in S_{i - 1}$, then $\sigma^{-1}(i)$ is greater than $i - 1$ distinct elements of $S_i$, so it must equal $i$.  Then (1) just says that $\sigma$ is order-preserving on $S_{i - 1}$.  (Ah, and now I see that I read the formal definition and missed the informal description of $S_i$, which, as @SamHopkins says, doesn't match the formal definition.  If you did mean the informal definition, then what's the (total?) order on $S_i$?)

@SamHopkins Updated

@LSpice iodated

Your update makes less sense. Now each $S_i$ is a two element set, so there are only two "permutations" of it (if permutations are understood in the usual sense as bijections from a finite set to itself).

@SamHopkins final update hopefully

In condition 1, shouldn't it be $a,b\in\mathbb N$ rather than $a\ne S_{i-1}$ and $b\ne S_{i-1}$? Otherwise one can take, say, $a=S_{i-2}$ with no "natural ordering". And even if $a,b$ are numbers, $\sigma^{-1}(a)$ and $\sigma^{-1}(b)$ may be not numbers but some $S_i$ - how do you compare them?

Can you do an example? Say the case $i=3$ or $i=4$? Clearly you have something specific in mind but it seems you are having trouble communicating it.

Is the following correct?$$\begin{array}{rl}S_1&={1}\S_2&={1,2,{1}}\S_3&={1,2,3,{1},{1,2,{1}}}\S_4&={1,2,3,4,{1},{1,2,{1}},{1,2,3,{1},{1,2,{1}}}}\end{array}$$
